# Using IO inside the ST monad and runSTUArray

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm just starting to experiment with monad transformers so I may have missed something trivial. Anyway: how can I print from inside the ST monad?

Example code:  I want to create code that is almost as fast as C, by reading and writing as quickly as possible to memory, with C-like for loops. I have an `ST` monad action that safely mutates an unboxed array that I run with `runSTUArray`.

My question is, how can I use `IO` actions inside the `ST` action?  If it was a `State` monad action, I could use the `StateT` transformer to lift the `IO` actions to, but how is that done for the `ST` monad?

Example: ST. -- how can I print form inside the ST monad?

```hs
import Control.Monad.ST (ST)
import Data.Array.Base ( STUArray(STUArray), newArray, readArray, writeArray )
import Data.Array.ST (runSTUArray)
import Data.Array.Unboxed ( elems )
import Control.Monad (forM_)

test :: IO ()
test = print . elems $ runSTUArray action
  where
    action :: ST s (STUArray s Int Int)
    action = do
        arr <- newArray (1,10) 1
        forM_ [3..10] $ \i -> do
            -- liftIO . print $ "i is " ++ show i.   --- <--- How should I do this?
            x1 <- readArray arr (i-1)
            x2 <- readArray arr (i-2)
            writeArray arr i (x1+x2)
        return arr
```

Example: StateT, -- here it is possible to lift the `print` to use it inside the monad/

```hs
import Data.Array.IArray (listArray, (!), (//), elems)
import Data.Array (Array)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict (StateT (runStateT), get, put)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO(liftIO))
import Control.Monad (forM_)

test :: IO ()
test = do
    let n = listArray (1,10) [1..] :: Array Int Int
    (_,x) <- runStateT action n
    print $ elems x
    return ()

    where action = do
            forM_ [3..10] $ \i -> do
                x <- get
                liftIO . print $ "i is " ++ show i.  -- <--- here printing works fine
                put (x // [(i, x!(i-1) + x!(i-2))])
```

Comment: `ST` is designed to allow reading/writing variables, but to disallow IO. You could adapt your code to use the `IO` monad instead of `ST`.

Comment: If it is purely for debugging then you can use [`traceM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't print from an `ST` action, you print from an `IO` action. Luckily for you, there are [`IOUArray`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array-IO.html#t:IOUArray) -- and they are even [`STUArray`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/src/Data.Array.IO.Internals.html#IOUArray) under the hood, so there can be no fear of performance lost.

Comment: Using `MArray` and such, it's pretty easy to write code that'll work in either. I don't know the canonical equivalent for `IORef`/`STRef`, but I know there is one.

Comment: Thanks for your tips! But there is a [monad tranformer version of the ST Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/STMonadTrans-0.4.6/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Trans.html) and it feels like one should be able to use it, and just imply lift the print, as one can do for the State monad (which is built from the StateT monad transformer).

Comment: If you lifted the print, and ran it, that'd work...and then you'd get a result out in the IO monad.  That doesn't really help you.  The ST monad is specifically designed to forbid you from doing this.